# How can I solve the error of Smart Contract?

Tags: smartcontracts, nearprotocol

I try to Call Smart Contract by NEAR Protocol for the first time.
Please tell me how can I solve the error as follows.

1. I have created Testnet NEAR Account.
2. I have compiled "Counter" Contract by using this example "https://github.com/near-examples/rust-counter/blob/master/contract/src/lib.rs".
3. I have deployed this contract to the testnet by using "near cli", and it has been succeed.
4. I call "veiw function" of near cli,Error Returned.

```
% near view Counter get_num '{}'
View call: Counter.get_num({})
An error occured
Error: [-32000] Server error: Account ID Counter is invalid
    at /Users/shin.takahashi/.nodebrew/node/v14.14.0/lib/node_modules/near-cli/node_modules/near-api-js/lib/providers/json-rpc-provider.js:322:31
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at async Object.exponentialBackoff [as default] (/Users/shin.takahashi/.nodebrew/node/v14.14.0/lib/node_modules/near-cli/node_modules/near-api-js/lib/utils/exponential-backoff.js:7:24)
    at async JsonRpcProvider.sendJsonRpc (/Users/shin.takahashi/.nodebrew/node/v14.14.0/lib/node_modules/near-cli/node_modules/near-api-js/lib/providers/json-rpc-provider.js:297:24)
    at async JsonRpcProvider.query (/Users/shin.takahashi/.nodebrew/node/v14.14.0/lib/node_modules/near-cli/node_modules/near-api-js/lib/providers/json-rpc-provider.js:109:22)
    at async Account.viewFunction (/Users/shin.takahashi/.nodebrew/node/v14.14.0/lib/node_modules/near-cli/node_modules/near-api-js/lib/account.js:356:24)
    at async exports.callViewFunction (/Users/shin.takahashi/.nodebrew/node/v14.14.0/lib/node_modules/near-cli/index.js:75:48)
    at async Object.handler (/Users/shin.takahashi/.nodebrew/node/v14.14.0/lib/node_modules/near-cli/utils/exit-on-error.js:52:9)
TypedError: [-32000] Server error: Account ID Counter is invalid
    at /Users/shin.takahashi/.nodebrew/node/v14.14.0/lib/node_modules/near-cli/node_modules/near-api-js/lib/providers/json-rpc-provider.js:322:31
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at async Object.exponentialBackoff [as default] (/Users/shin.takahashi/.nodebrew/node/v14.14.0/lib/node_modules/near-cli/node_modules/near-api-js/lib/utils/exponential-backoff.js:7:24)
    at async JsonRpcProvider.sendJsonRpc (/Users/shin.takahashi/.nodebrew/node/v14.14.0/lib/node_modules/near-cli/node_modules/near-api-js/lib/providers/json-rpc-provider.js:297:24)
    at async JsonRpcProvider.query (/Users/shin.takahashi/.nodebrew/node/v14.14.0/lib/node_modules/near-cli/node_modules/near-api-js/lib/providers/json-rpc-provider.js:109:22)
    at async Account.viewFunction (/Users/shin.takahashi/.nodebrew/node/v14.14.0/lib/node_modules/near-cli/node_modules/near-api-js/lib/account.js:356:24)
    at async exports.callViewFunction (/Users/shin.takahashi/.nodebrew/node/v14.14.0/lib/node_modules/near-cli/index.js:75:48)
    at async Object.handler (/Users/shin.takahashi/.nodebrew/node/v14.14.0/lib/node_modules/near-cli/utils/exit-on-error.js:52:9) {
  type: 'UntypedError',
  context: undefined
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Counter` is not a valid account-id. [Uppercase letters in accounts-id are not allowed](https://nomicon.io/DataStructures/Account.html#account-id-rules)). You need to pass the proper `account-id`.

I would expected your account-id to be something of the form `takahashi.testnet` or [`dev-1623565709996-68004511819798`](https://explorer.testnet.near.org/accounts/dev-1623565709996-68004511819798) (if contract was deployed using `near dev-deploy` command).

This is how you can deploy to testnet using `dev-deploy`, and call view function using `near-cli`:

```sh
❯ near --version
2.0.2

❯ near dev-deploy out/main.wasm
Starting deployment. Account id: dev-1623565709996-68004511819798, node: https://rpc.testnet.near.org, helper: https://helper.testnet.near.org, file: out/main.wasm
Transaction Id 5eTde2dUw5QTA8hbpWvAw4ABary64Tsnj9FzBCPS9Ne
Done deploying to dev-1623565709996-68004511819798

❯ near view dev-1623565709996-68004511819798 get_num '{}'
View call: dev-1623565709996-68004511819798.get_num({})
0
```

If you are using mainnet network (instead of testnet), you need to let near-cli knows about this, by setting the environment variable:

```
❯ export NEAR_ENV=mainnet
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! My problem have been solved by your replying.But official document of "near cli" is hard to understand. because first parameter of "near call" is indicated "contractName",but it is not.

Comment: Thanks for bringing this to our attention. By contractName it implies account-id of the contract, but I understand the confusion.

Comment: Opened an issue on near-cli about this: https://github.com/near/near-cli/issues/793